# How to connect and send data to Bluetooth form AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, bluetooth

I need to connect and send data to Bluetooth from Action Script 3 (AS3)

if there is any idea I'll be glad for your help

Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

Wiimotes connect/send data through bluetooth.

I had a quick look through the [WiiFlashServer](http://wiiflash.bytearray.org/?page_id=50) java source.
It uses a [ServerSocket](http://www.jdocs.com/javase/7.b12/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and it seems to send binary data to flash via
the [Socket](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) class.

You could either adapt some of that code to suit your needs, or build a Socket server in your language of choice and send the data to flash sockets.

HTH,
George